# iphone sdk. Is it possible to read system settings?

Tags: iphone, settings, system

I need to determine if certain system settings have been set on the iphone. i.e. Whether or not particular sounds are enabled/disabled so I can decide whether or not to play sound in my own app.  Is it possible to read the system settings, and if so, how?

Thanks

Fitto

Answer (score 0):

You can [detect if the silent switch is on](http://randomsnippetsofusefulstuff.blogspot.com/2009/07/iphone-silent-modeswitch-state.html) or not, is this what you are after?

```
CFStringRef state;
UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(CFStringRef);
AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute, &propertySize, &state);
if(CFStringGetLength(state) > 0)
   NSLog(@"Vibration Off");
else
   NSLog(@"Vibration On");
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm specifically after detecting whether keyboard clicks are enabled or not.  This is so I can give my own feedback to user-defined input.

Comment: I very much doubt you would be able to access that level of detail. I could be wrong though.